# Subtract from the previous row R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df <- data.frame(start=c(5,4,2),end=c(2,6,3))

start end
    5   2
    4   6
    2   3
```

And I want the following result:

```
start end diff
    5   2 
    4   6    1
    2   3   -1
```

Essentially it is:

`end[2] (second row) - start[1] = 6-5=1`

and `end[3] - start[2] = 3-4 = -1`

What is a good way of doing this in R?

Comment: Or `library(dplyr);mutate(df, diff= end-lag(start))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just a simple vector subtraction should work

```
df$diff <- c(NA,df[2:nrow(df), 2] - df[1:(nrow(df)-1), 1])

  start end diff
1     5   2   NA
2     4   6    1
3     2   3   -1
```

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis at end of df$diff statement.  Statement should read: df$diff <- c(NA,df[2:nrow(df), 2] - df[1:(nrow(df)-1), 1])

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,value:=end-shift(start,1,type="lag")]
   start end value
1:     5   2    NA
2:     4   6     1
3:     2   3    -1
```