# Convert Values in R

Tags: r

[image]

I want to convert my NA into 0 and other values into 1 without affecting my ID variable

Comment: Could you make some effort and provide a reproducible example?

Comment: In addition to the comment of @Pascal: some info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @ arkun i did not know about the image , please accept my apology for downvote

Comment: It's okay.  I knew that being new to the site, you were not aware of it.  Not a big deal.  Otherwise, your question and expected answer is clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
df1[-1] <- (!is.na(df1[-1]))+0L
df1
#  ID condimenti occhialli pane prontoTaway surgelati utensili
#1  1          0         0    1           0         0        0
#2  2          0         1    0           0         0        0
#3  3          0         0    0           0         1        0
#4  4          0         0    0           0         1        0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in 2:ncol(df1)){
  set(df1, i= NULL, j=j, value= (is.na(df1[[j]]))+0L)
 }
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs((!is.na(.))+0L), -ID)
```

data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ID = 1:4, condimenti = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
 occhialli = c(NA, 
"CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)", NA, NA), pane =
c("OCCHIALI E OROLOGI", 
NA, NA, NA), prontoTaway = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), surgelati = c(NA, 
NA, "PRONTO CALDO TAKE AWAY", "PRONTO CALDO TAKe AWAY"), utensili = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "condimenti", "occhialli", "pane", 
"prontoTaway", "surgelati", "utensili"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: From my point of you, your answer exempts the OP to make some effort to ask reasonable question. You did all the work for him.

Comment: @Pascal I did look at his other posts where he provided an example data, but I think being a newbie, he may not know whether an image is suitable or not.  But, downvoting for a correct answer is not good.

Comment: This is my position and my choice.

Comment: @Pascal Okay, not a problem.

Comment: @Pascal if I look at a recent answer by you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448709/subtract-from-the-previous-row-r/30448772#30448772 it may also have duplicates and if the OP made some effort, he could have easily find it by himself

Comment: So you waste your time searching recent answers I gave. Up to you. Feel free to downvote all my answers.

Comment: @Pascal No, I saw that some time ago, just remembered because you made a point.  Anyway, it is your choice and I respect it.

Comment: @Pascal Also, from the OP's post, the question is reasonable and he did stated it clearly and that is position.

Comment: We have a different viewpoint on what is a reasonable question. Anyway, your answer provides what the OP is looking for. For the duplicate, I usually do check before answering. It seems I failed for this one. I "repaired" the fault.

Comment: @Pascal I wouldn't delete an answer just because somebody found it a duplicate.  But, it is up to you.  Also, whether I waste time or not, it is completely up to me.

Comment: Once again, it is my choice.

Comment: my 2c: [Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)